# How could I obtain confusion matrix in R?

Tags: r, roc, confusion-matrix, auc

I have a table `holdouTable` with the column of prediction `pred`.

`library(precrec)`

`head(holdoutTable)`

> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDfm4.png)
> Species                  geometry       pred
> 1       1 POINT (38.80153 54.88964) 0.33363164
> 2       1   POINT (37.83133 55.701) 0.56814105
> 3       1 POINT (36.48579 55.71794) 0.09608355
> 4       1 POINT (37.54231 55.58439) 0.10376186
> 5       1   POINT (37.3788 54.9587) 0.07254712
> 6       1 POINT (37.40738 55.00861) 0.11294458

I calculate ROC AUC and plot it, but I do not know how to get confusion matrix? Could anybody to help me?

`holdotTable$pred <- predict(mx, hddata, type = "cloglog")`

`precrec_hd <- evalmod(scores = holdotTable$pred, labels = holdotTable$Species)`

`autoplot(precrec_hd, curvetype = "ROC")`

`precrec_hd`

Model name Dataset ID Curve type       AUC
1         m1          1        ROC 0.8434492
2         m1          1        PRC 0.7676958

P.S. Previously people asked me to put output of code instead screenshot of my data. I am not sure that I do it successful now, because I just copy form console and paste (I putted image of `holdoutTable` in any case). If you can advise me how to put it in right way,I will be glad to know. Thanks!

Comment: The correct way to share data is using `dput`. Read about it here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596326

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
require('caret')
require('e1071')
df <- data.frame(predicted = holdotTable$pred, actual = holdotTable$Species)
#assuming pred column contains the predicted species
confusionMatrix(data = df$predicted, reference = df$actual)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but the main problem is underlying in the column "pred". So I have continiuos values (probability), but to create conf matrix I need a class (0 or 1).

Comment: @DianaKoldasbayeva If the choice is binary, you just assign the predicted class based on this probability (1 if >0.5, and 0 otherwise).